# Screen Overlay Issue

Tags: android, permissions, overlay

When I request a permission, Screen Overlay issue happens. So, it is impossible to get all permissions from user.

I tried to turn off all the apps on "Draw over other apps", but still same.

How should I solve this problem?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use a third party library called Ted Permission. It is easy and efficient and it allow asking multiple permissions at a time.

Gradle Dependancy:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'gun0912.ted:tedpermission:2.1.0'
}
```

Make PermissionListener:

```
PermissionListener permissionlistener = new PermissionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPermissionGranted() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPermissionDenied(ArrayList<String> deniedPermissions) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Denied\n" + deniedPermissions.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    };
```

Start TedPermission:

```
TedPermission.with(this)
    .setPermissionListener(permissionlistener)
    .setDeniedMessage("If you reject permission,you can not use this service\n\nPlease turn on permissions at [Setting] > [Permission]")
    .setPermissions(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
    .check();
```

For more info check this link

https://github.com/ParkSangGwon/TedPermission